# How to make a subfolder unreachable and files undownloadable from root directory using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a subfolder, named `backups` unreachable and files within it downloadable with the aid of `.htaccess` placed in the home directory. I don't want to create a secondary `.htaccess` file in the subfolder.

I did several rewrite and deny commands but no effect.

Comment: Please include what you have tried. And exactly where, in relation to other directives, you have placed these rules. You may have made just a simple mistake, or there may be something more fundamental that is failing, eg. Are `.htaccess` overrides even enabled? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following with mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file to block (ie. 403 Forbidden) any requests to `/backups` or `/backups/<anything>`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block any HTTP requests to "/backups" subdirectory
RewriteRule ^backups($|/) - [F]
```

Note that when used in `.htaccess`, the URL-path that then `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash.

Alternatively, use mod_authz_core inside an Apache expression to target just the `/backups` subdirectory. For example:

```
# Block any HTTP requests to "/backups" subdirectory
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/backups($|/)#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```